# How does the press "call" elections in the United States?

Tags: election

The New York Times is currently (8:14pm, March 8, 2016), saying that Clinton has won the Mississippi primary. However, they also say she has 0% of the vote, and 0% of the precincts are reporting.

I see similar cases--calling an election with 0% reporting--nearly every election cycle.

How do they make these calls?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this question](http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/10050/4666).

Comment: I've seen the press call an election and then take it back yesterday

Answer (score -2):

They use exit polling of voters in conjunction with vote results.

Comment: The question is *how* they make the decision, i.e., the process they use.  Incomplete data is certainly involved, but how is it weighted and used?

Comment: That's all up to the people they hire to do it and is a trade secret.